# Conditional column in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a two new columns in below data frame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"store_id": ["1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3"], 
               "units":  ["5 or less", "17", "5 or less", "5 or less", "28", "15"], 
               "unit_percent":  ["","0.37","","","0.57","0.48" ]
              })
```

**1. Sell column:**

- if units percent is null then "5" else units divide by unit_percent

**2. total_sell_per_store** : I need total sell per store. if there are multiple rows for storeid, i need value in only one

- use sell where unit_percent is not null.
- if there are multiple rows for storeid where unit percent is not null then use the highest sell.(i.e storeid 3)
- If there aren't any rows for storeid where unit percent is not null then use the sum of sells for each rows. (i.e storeid 2)

[image: df]

Result

[image: result]

Comment: I think your question will be more likely to get an answer if you show that you have made a good faith effort. Where are you stuck? Can you provide some of the code or documentation you have looked at so far?

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code? Did you try to use `.apply(your_function, axis=1)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For column `sell` you can use `.apply()` with own function like

```
def func(row):
    if not row["unit_percent"]:
        return 5
    else:
        return int(float(row["units"]) / float(row["unit_percent"]))

df['sell'] = df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

---

Other column seems more complex and it may need `group_by` to work with every `storeid` separatelly. At this moment I don't have example for this column.

---

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "store_id": ["1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3"], 
    "units":  ["5 or less", "17", "5 or less", "5 or less", "28", "15"], 
    "unit_percent":  ["","0.37","","","0.57","0.48" ]
})

def func(row):
    if not row["unit_percent"]:
        return 5
    else:
        return int(float(row["units"]) / float(row["unit_percent"]))

df['sell'] = df.apply(func, axis=1)

print(df)
```

Result:

```
  store_id      units unit_percent  sell
0        1  5 or less                  5
1        1         17         0.37    45
2        2  5 or less                  5
3        2  5 or less                  5
4        3         28         0.57    49
5        3         15         0.48    31
```